# Implementing Slick Carousel - New to JS

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I'm totally new to Javascript as of today. I'm trying to get Slick Carousel working.

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.5/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.5/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="your-class">
    <div>
      <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/958_placeholders/placehold.gif">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.your-class').slick();
    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.5/slick.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Include Jquery in your script references

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If any solution was helpful please accept the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add jQuery dependency to your code as i said in comments because  you are using dollar sign `$`. Just add a line of code from this:
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/.

Like this one
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

But **BEFORE** slick library.
(Yes, not before your script tag. Thanks  josedefreitasc.)

Comment: Thats correct, you need to add jquery library before the slick plugin http://jsfiddle.net/znrgd66s/

Answer (score 0):

the selector is incorrect, put the dot to make it work.

```
$('.your-class').slick();
```

Comment: In addition to this, he will need to make sure `jQuery 1.7` is included as that is a dependency.

Comment: Fixed the selector and it's still not working. How would I include jQuery 1.7 as a dependency? What would that look like?